# Save doesn't work with Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I got an Entity called "Data" which contain an attribute called "highscore"

I got my NSManagedObject class :

```
class Data: NSManagedObject
{
    @NSManaged var highscore: NSNumber
}
```

And I tried theses few lines :

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Data",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
let data = Data(entity: entityDescription!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

data.highscore = 100

managedObjectContext.insertObject(data)
try! managedObjectContext.save()

print(data.highscore)
```

So when I run my app, everything works fine, the console prints "100". But when I comment out the line data.highscore = 100 and I relaunch my app, the console prints "0" instead of "100". 
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: If you only removed `data.highscore = 100` then the code you have shown would create a new instance of `Data` with that entity's default value for `highscore`. What are you trying to do, what did you expect to see?

Comment: Oh, I thought that during the first launch, I'm setting the value for highscore to 100 and then save it, so during the second launch the highscore value would be 100. So this create a new instance of Data instead of changing the saved one ? That's not what I'm trying to do

Comment: Check if your managed object context has parent context - it may be problem why not saving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you run your app, it creates a new instance of `Data`. That's what this line does:

```
let data = Data(entity: entityDescription!,
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
```

It isn't that Core Data isn't saving, it's that you're never looking up any of the data you save. If you want to get a previous instance, you need to look it up in your persistent store. Look into `NSFetchRequest` to find previously-saved data.

Answer (score 0):

I all you are storing is a single value for High Score, why not use NSDefaults?  I gave an example of the earlier in this question [Comparing speed values issue(what ever i am getting from CLLocationManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080858/comparing-speed-values-issuewhat-ever-i-am-getting-from-cllocationmanager/35081077?noredirect=1#comment57889072_35081077)